# logic proposition simplify version

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to know the simplify version of

$((((A => B) | A) \& \sim B) => f)$

is $( \sim A V B) $?

or

$((A V B) \& ( \sim A V B))$ ?

Comment: What does the vertical line mean ?

Comment: Is this a homework question? What did you try yourself?

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah  it means “or”

Comment: @kili " or " is represented by "V".

Comment: where does $f$ go ?

Answer (score 1):

$$(((A \Rightarrow B) \lor A)\land \neg B)$$
$$(((\neg A \lor B) \lor A)\land \neg B)$$
$$(((\neg A \lor A) \lor B)\land \neg B)$$
$$(((\neg A \lor A) \lor B)\land \neg B)$$
$$(B \land \neg B)$$
$$\text{False}$$